# Finding a function $f$ such that if $X \sim Poi(\lambda)$, then $E[f(X)]=λ(λ−1)...(λ−k+1)$

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

> Let $k∈N, \lambda \in \Bbb R$ and $X∼\operatorname{Poi}(λ)$. Is there an explicit function $f$ such that $E[f(X)]=λ(λ−1)...(λ−k+1)$?

I can prove that there exists a linear combination of the moments that works, because they contain a polynomial of every degree, but the coefficients of the moments are Stirling numbers so this linear combination is not explicit. I'd like to have a more concrete $f$ is possible.

Such a function is termed an unbiased estimator for $k! \binom {\lambda} {k}$.

Comment: What is the definition of the binomial coefficient when $\lambda$ is not an integer?

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but we have $$ \mathbb{E}\left[ (1 + \log(1+z))^X \right] = (1+z)^{\lambda} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{\lambda}{n}z^n. $$ So differentiating both sides $k$ times w.r.t. $z$ and plugging $z = 0$ gives $$ \mathbb{E}\left[ \left.\frac{\partial^k}{\partial z^k}\right|_{r=0} (1+\log(1+z))^X \right] = \lambda(\lambda-1)\cdots(\lambda-k+1). $$